# Defining opacity when using Imagick::compositeImage in PHP

Tags: php, opacity, imagick

The problem is simple:

I want to composite an image on another with opacity.

```
$logo = createLogo($size); // returns Imagick object
$image->compositeImage($logo, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, x, y, width, height);
```

I would like to set the opacity of the $logo. It seems $logo->setImageOpacity is deprecated. What is the new way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$logo->evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, 0.3, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

Where 0.3 is the percentage for opacity value, max 1.0, min 0.0.